# How do you connect to a remote on prem service fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I installed a local Service Fabric cluster on a Shared Dev' PC, I was hoping to be able to use this environment for debugging and initial deployments for multiple team members.

However I can not seem to connect to this cluster from a remote PC, only locally.

I was wondering what I need to do to enable connection from within Visual Studio if possible, or from a browser?

I have opened the firewall up so it's not a port issue.

If I try to connect using the browser URL:      http://ComputerName:19080/Explorer/index.html

I get the following error:

```
SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, but only when I was entering Service Fabric Explorer for the first time. After a few trials in a period of about 30 minutes it started working, so I guess apart from cluster orchestration it needs some time to setup explorer.

Comment: I think that's if your connecting locally isn't it. Like running the explorer on the same machine as the Fabric Cluster... But I'll give it another try...

Comment: In the same scenario, I am able to connect to the SF Explorer without any problem, almost immediately after the cluster starts up. However, I cannot connect to the remote cluster via PowerShell or Visual Studio.